# Testlink new installation "DB Access Error - debug_print_backtrace() OUTPUT START"

Tags: sql, mariadb

[Testlink error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBUD8.png)  When I try to install Testlink on Workbench, this error occurs:

> DB Access Error - debug_print_backtrace()
>
> OUTPUT START  ATTENTION:
>   Enabling more debug info will produce path disclosure weakness
>   (CWE-200) 
>                   Having this additional Information could be useful for reporting 
>                   issue to development TEAM.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! There isn't enough detail in this question for it to be answerable. I'd recommend that you [edit] it to include the exact steps required to reproduce the problem. Your question will be better received if you also show some evidence of what you've already reasearched/tried to resolve the issue. See [ask].

Comment: @Amina were you able to find out what was the error?